# Creating goal funnel for account sign up using javascript

Tags: asp.net

I have a website which has got 4 steps for account sign up. I am trying to implement a google analytics funnel using javascript to find out how many people are gone through each step of sign up process.
I used asp.net wizard control for account sign up.Each step refers the same page(signup/default.aspx) with next and previous buttons.

```
protected void wzsignup_ActiveStepChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 string step = wzsignup.ActiveStep.ID.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //example of step name is personaldetails..

     string script = "var _gaq=_gaq || [];_gaq.push(['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-1' ]);_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'],'/{0}');(function(){{var ga=document.createElement('script');ga.type='text/javascript';ga.async=true;ga.src=('https:'==document.location.protocol?'https://ssl':'http://www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga,s);}})();";
     script = string.Format(script, step);
     HtmlGenericControl scriptTag = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
     scriptTag.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
     scriptTag.InnerHtml = script;
     this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(scriptTag);
}
```

How do i get the report for signup steps?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation google has on this is pretty good.  There are two pieces that you will need to do.  The first is to set up page view tracking by specifying a virtual url for each of the steps of your conversion funnel.  Here's the documentation link for that:

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1116091#identical

The second part is setting up the goal within google analytics where you can create the goal and specify the steps for the funnel:

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1116091#funnels

I highly recommend that you read the google documentation on this... they outline these steps pretty well.